# Cannot connect to AWS instance running Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, firewall

I have an AWS instance running Apache server.
Apache is running when accessed from the local machine.
RDP connection through the elastic IP is working.
Port 80 is open for the security group
However, the elastic IP is not accessible from the browser.
Any ideas?

Comment: When you try to access Port 80, what result do you get in your browser?

Answer (score 4):

It could be a Security Groups is not configured to allow HTTP.

1. Go to http://aws.amazon.com  Sign in.
2. Click on EC2. Then click on Security Groups. Click on the Security Group that your instance is using.
3. Click on Inbound tab. Click on Edit button.
4. In here, add you IP address (or Anywhere) for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not enough information for me to provide a definitive answer.

Here are some questions you can ask to help you figure out what may be wrong, however:

- What happens when you run `telnet 50.40.30.20 80` (where
  `50.40.30.20` is your EIP)?
- You mention that RDP is working, is this a Windows instance (which requires port 3389 to be open for RDP)? or is it a Linux instance that requires port 22 to be open for SSH?
- If Linux, is SELinux running? If so, you may find
  [this](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html) helpful
  in disabling it temporarily or permanently to see if it has an impact on your ability to hit Apache.